# cannot get response from the function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect php with mysql so I write the code like this:

```
<?php
// Create connection
echo "1";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pwd");
echo "2";
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

but i dont get any response, there is only a "1" on the page. I'm sure that the uname and pwd is correct. Any advices?

Comment: mysql and mysqli are two completely different APIs. Using them together is nonsense.

Comment: Use `mysqli_connect` and not `mysql_connect` plus you need to select a DB using `mysqli_select_db` or add a fourth parameter. I.e.: `$con = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "db_name");`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: the default db isn't required. in fact, ALL of the parameters can be omitted. They're all optional and will simply pull defaults from php.ini if not provided.

Comment: @deceze sorry, that's a typing mistake.

Comment: @TrueBlue: turn on error_reporting and display_errors. If you don't get 2, then something's killing the script and all debug/error output's been disabled so you never see what the real problem was.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried what you said, but still didn't get a response.

Comment: Since you're running this on `localhost` and assuming that it's on your own machine; have you checked if MySQL is installed, properly configured and running? @TrueBlue

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's running.

Comment: You may need to specify a (*specific*) port then. @TrueBlue and check all your `.ini` files.

Comment: You're welcome @TrueBlue See this page also => http://www.codingforums.com/mysql/162427-how-determine-port-mysql-running-localhost.html might help. Then Google "localhost port mysql"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_connect` function instead of `mysql_connect`,

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","root","pwd","my_db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: sorry, that's a silly typing mistake. I used mysqli_connect it still doesn't work

Comment: are you use WAMP server

Comment: Nope, I install them on the linux server

Comment: linux support msqli_connect.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `mysqli` extension not enabled in your `php.ini` configuration.
After enabling the extension restart the Apache server and try again the running the code.